# Terraform error creating a pattern of a aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Im trying to create a metric filter like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "name_resource" {
  name           = "MetricName"
  pattern        = "{($.errorCode="*UnauthorizedOperation") || ($.errorCode="AccessDenied*")}"
  log_group_name = var.log_group_cloudtrail_name


  metric_transformation {
    name          = "MetricName"
    namespace     = "MetricNameSpace"
    value         = "1"
    default_value = "0"
  }
}
```

However Im getting this error:

```
│ Error: Missing newline after argument
│
│   on metric_filter.tf line 3, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "name_resource":
│    3:   pattern        = "{($.errorCode="*UnauthorizedOperation") || ($.errorCode="AccessDenied*")}"
│
│ An argument definition must end with a newline.
```

I think that the problem is the quotes, but if I try to use single quotes, I get another error because they are not available.

How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [escape](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences) the quotes:

```
pattern        = "{($.errorCode=\"*UnauthorizedOperation\") || ($.errorCode=\"AccessDenied*\")}"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I tried that but in the terraform plan I see this: 
    
  + pattern        = "{($.errorCode=\"*UnauthorizedOperation\") || ($.errorCode=\"AccessDenied*\")}"

I dont want the symbol "\" in the pattern when I create the resource. will it work?